# Sharepoint DB Server Rename

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

i have one application server and one DB server i have installed MOSS on App server and its content DB is on the DB server.  due to policy reasons i had to rename the Sharepoint database server

now the problem is MOSS is not working. So how do i make it work 
thier is stsadm command renameserver but that is to change the host name

Answer (score 1):

Go into Central Admin, and under Content Databases, remove the database from the web application. Unfortunately, you can't reattach a content db using Central Admin, so you need to use stsadm. Here's the command:

```
STSADM –o addcontentdb –url <URL name> -databasename <database name> -databaseserver <database server name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for this command??

[stsadm -o setconfigdb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261712.aspx)

You have to use it when the the database server are renamed or you want to connect the MOSS to other config database.

In case of renaming app db you have to do it with "stsadm -o addcontentdb" like the previuos answer said.